# When trying to contribute a model I get "abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")"

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

when I use the

hg commit

command it gives me that error... How do I set a username?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13792/when-trying-to-contribute-a-model-i-get-%22abort:-no-username-supplied-(see-%22hg-help-config%22)%22/) by [Blui](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2681/blui/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can either specify a user for the commit:

```
hg commit -u <your username>
```

Or set the default user in your `.hgrc` file so it is used for every commit. Open the file:

```
gedit ~/.hgrc
```

And add this, note that the email is actually in angled brackets `<>`

```
[ui]
username = <your username> <<your email>>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blui](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2681/blui/) on 2016-07-04**:
Thank you!